# Hide keyboard when selecting another UITextField w/ UIPickerView error

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

I'm trying to hide the keyboard when the user selects a `UITextField`. I currently have three text fields: two `UIPickerView` (controlled by the same picker) and a textinput field. When I click "return" or on the background, the keyboard disappears via a `resignFirstResponder` call.

PROBLEM:

When I am currently editing the text input field and then immediately select the `UITextField` w/ `UIPickerView` functionality, the keyboard doesn't disappear. I feel like i've tried every solution and am beating by head against a wall...

CODE:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [pickerView setHidden:YES];
    if (fldQuiver.editing == YES) {
        [fldTitle resignFirstResponder];
        [fldQuiver resignFirstResponder];
        [pickerView setHidden:NO];
        variabla = 1;
    }else if (fldCategory.editing == YES) {
        [fldTitle resignFirstResponder];
        [fldCategory resignFirstResponder];
        [pickerView setHidden:NO];
        variabla = 2;
    }
    NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla);
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDITED CODE FOR PRINCE:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;        // return NO to disallow editing.
{
    //set logic for picker view here
    if (textField == fldQuiver)
    {
        variabla = 1;
    }
    else if (textField == fldCategory) {
        variabla = 2;
    }
    else
    {
    }
    NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla);
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];

    if (textField == fldQuiver)
    {
        [fldTitle resignFirstResponder];
        [pickerView setHidden:NO];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (textField == fldCategory) {
        [fldTitle resignFirstResponder];
        [pickerView setHidden:NO];
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [pickerView setHidden:YES];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

ALSO: I have "synthesized" and declared `@property` `fldQuiver` and `fldCategory`. I have `IBOutlet` for `fldTitle`, `fldQuiver`, `fldCategory`.

The `pickerView` is loaded with an array based on variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` `delegate` method for this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;        // return NO to disallow editing.
{
   //set logic for picker view here 
   if (textField == fldQuiver) 
   {
      //picker view hidden or show here
      return NO;
   }
   else if (textField == fldCategory) {
       //picker view hidden or show here
      return NO;
   }
   else
   {
      return YES;
   }

}
```

Comment: I implemented this code -- see my edit. It doesn't load the picker with contents and when i am editing the text input field (fldTitle) and then select either fldCategory or fldQuiver the keyboard still is displayed.

Comment: also, not sure what is meant by your comments so i may have done it wrong... sorry for my limited knowledge

Comment: the pickerview is loaded with an array based on variabla.

Comment: see solution in my original post ... hope this helps someone and saves them days of looking around. Thanks Prince....

Answer (score 0):

set delegate for text field

```
textField.delegate=self;

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
...........
[textField resignFirstResponder];  //it common for all text field,so not use multi resignFirstResponder
............
}
```

Comment: where do I set the delegate (line 1)

Comment: set delegate for next to allocation of textfield & set text delegat in .h file, ex @interface filename : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>